# What does this cast assign? C Style Casting

Tags: c++, c, casting

this is my first question on here.
I am currently trying to understand how this code works.
I basically want to assign a certain value to an array named "hv" of type `uint8_t`.
I do not quite understand what this cast does/how it works.

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    hv[i] = *(uint16_t *)(h1 + 8 + i * 2);
}
```

I do understand that it is trying to cast the 2nd part to an uint16_t pointer but i do not know what the first asterisk does.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It dereferences the pointer.

Comment: Oh yeah, now it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: please don't incite to violence on this site! Please choose your language: C or C++.

Comment: show the definitions of `hv` and `h`. We need to know their type. Also this cast looks very suspicious.

Comment: Both are of Type uint8_t as stated above

Comment: @ConIsoInc don't tell tales about the code. Show the definitions of the variables. We are trained to better and faster understand actual code than description of it. Plus things can get lost in descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `h1` is a pointer. Otherwise this makes no sense at all.

The expression `(h1 + 8 + i * 2)` will give a new pointer, which is offseted relative to `h1`. Exactly by now much depends on `sizeof(*h1)`. The offset vill be `(8+i*2)*sizeof(*h1)` bytes.

Putting `(uint_16_t *)` in front of this will convert it to a uint_16_t pointer. Putting an asterisk in front of that will give you the content of that memory location, treated as an uint_16_t.

The code is equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    uint_16_t * tmp = (uint16_t *)(h1 + 8 + i * 2);
    hv[i] = *tmp;
}
```

Comment: yeah makes sense, h1 is an array of type uint_8 tho. Sry forgot to mention